# Is it possible to make the F5 key always preform a hard refresh in browsers?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, refresh

Are there browser configuration settings or other ways to make a single press of the <kbd>F5</kbd> key preform a hard refresh of the currently loaded page? Ordinarily hard refresh is achieved via pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> but I would like to remove the extra key requirements and preform it on just <kbd>F5</kbd> alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done with a macro if you're willing to set it up. You could use **Microsoft Mouse and Keyboard Center** and setup the macro with that.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/mouse-and-keyboard-center-download-f5b10905-7887-eedb-2f1c-d0737a36a3b2

Then press the Windows Start button and tap on ‘Microsoft Mouse and Keyboard Center’

Step 1:
Now using the Hotkeys tab, tap on ‘create/add new hotkey. You can then move to an existing hotkey from the list to reassign it another function

Step 2:
Choose the key you like to make a hotkey

Step 3:
Now from the command list, choose a command for your new hotkey.

Step 4:
Tap ‘OK’ to create your hotkey.

Comment: Thank you. It seem setting up a hotkey is the only way. I am on linux so I used a program called Autokey and it was a different process to set it up but same concept.